# Where and how to start implementing a Java program that searches a phrase example “red or green" in a text file,

Tags: java

I want to implementing a Java program that searches a phrase example “red or green, blue car, red and blue” in a text file, and returns a match even if it is not a complete match for the phrase, and if there is no even half match the program should return no match.

if I am searching "red car" and the the string line in the text file contains "red and blue" I want the program to return red which is half a match of what I was searching.

Any help is very much appreciated

This is what I have done so far, all this does is find the exact words

```
public class StringSearch 
   {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
      {
        String key = "red yellow";
        String strLine;
        try
          {
    FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("C:\\textfile.txt");
    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
          BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {    
          if(key.equals(strLine))
         {
          System.out.println(" Match For " + strLine );
        }
        else 
         {
         System.out.println( "No Match For "   + key);

        }
     // Print the content on the console
    }
        //Close the input stream
        in.close();

        }catch (Exception e){//Catch exception if any
            System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

But what I want to find is if I am searching "red" and the first line of the string in the text file I am searching contains "red car was stollen" and the second line contains just "red". I want to return two matches the first one being 100% match the socond being 50% match.

Comment: what did you try so far ??..post your code so that we can help you resolve it. welcome to SO:)

Comment: http://lucene.apache.org/core/ - unless you want/need to reinvent the wheel ("*many powerful query types: phrase queries, wildcard queries, proximity queries, range queries and more*")

Comment: "red fish, blue fish" - it's the SeussParser.

Comment: OK, so you need to parse your query phrase into individual words, look for the first word, then see if the remaining words follow.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to define your problem better, and to do that think about how what you'd do if you were telling someone else, who interpreted things very literally, how to do it.  How much of the input should they examine at one time?  Should what they examine span lines?  What precisely is a "half match"?  What is the sequence of steps they should take?

Comment: if I am searching "red car" and the the string line in the text file contains "red and blue" I want the program to return red which is half a match of what I was searching.

Any help is very much appreciated

Comment: @SalimShari -- OK, that's about one tenth of the description you need to work up.  Now work on the other nine-tenths.

Comment: Please help if you can, I would really appreciate

Answer (score 0):

This code might help You

```
import java.io.*;

public class searchfile {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            // Open the file c:\test.txt as a buffered reader
            BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("c:\\test.txt"));

            // Start a line count and declare a string to hold our current line.
            int linecount = 0;
                String line;

            // Let the user know what we are searching for
            System.out.println("Searching for " + args[0] + " in file...");

            // Loop through each line, stashing the line into our line variable.
            while (( line = bf.readLine()) != null)
            {
                    // Increment the count and find the index of the word
                    linecount++;
                    int indexfound = line.indexOf(args[0]);

                    // If greater than -1, means we found the word
                    if (indexfound > -1) {
                         System.out.println("Word was found at position " + indexfound + " on line " + linecount);
                    }
            }

            // Close the file after done searching
            bf.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IO Error Occurred: " + e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

and run it as 
`c:\>java searchfile "bluecar"`